# Matplotlib - cannot find Numpy header files

Tags: python, c++, macos, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph using matplotlib:

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

int main() {
    plt::plot({1,2,3,4});
    plt::show();
}
```

However, when I hit compile I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/matplotlibcpp.h:19:12: 
fatal error: 'numpy/arrayobject.h' file not found
```

This is how I compile:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

Please can someone explain what the problem is and how I can solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show how you compile

Comment: No prob. I have updated the question.

Comment: You need a -I flag with the folder containing the numpy headers

Comment: It compiles now. Thanks!

Comment: The former. It could help someone else.

Comment: Just for reference, where did you find the numpy folder?

Comment: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include' -- a different location to what i found on the internet. Is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that the numpy headers were not found in one of the default locations like `/usr/include`.

The solution is to find the include folder of your numpy installation and point the compiler to it with a `-I` flag.

Your command line should look something like

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Ex‌​tras/lib/python/nump‌​y/core/include -lpython2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding "#define WITHOUT_NUMPY" flag at top of mapplotlibcpp.h